# Как спрятать div при нажатиии в этом исполнении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, localstorage, display

Есть такой небольшой код для обратной связи и я тут заморочился с ним.
вопрос, как же при нажатии прятать то куда нажимал и открывать другой блок(что уже работает). И так же сделать наоборот, нажимая на второй блок(прячась) что бы открывался первый.

```
<a onclick="onclickVhod();" id="idExid"class="popup_toggle">
<div class="circlephone" style="transform-origin: center;"></div>
<div class="circle-fill" style="transform-origin: center;"></div>
<div class="img-circle" style="transform-origin: center;">
<div class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></div></div>
</a>    

<span onclick="onclickExid()" id="idVhod" ><span id="ugcontcal"></span></span>


<script>
var idVhod = document.getElementById('idVhod');

function onclickVhod() {
  idVhod.style.display = (idVhod.style.display == 'inline') ? '' : 'inline';
  localStorage.setItem('hide', idVhod.style.display); // сохраняем значение в ключ hide
}

if(localStorage.getItem('hide') == 'inline') { // если значение ключа hide "inline"
  document.getElementById('idVhod').style.display = 'inline';
}

var idExid = document.getElementById('idExid');

function onclickExid() {
  idExid.style.display = (idExid.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
  localStorage.setItem('hide', idExid.style.display); // сохраняем значение в ключ hide
}

if(localStorage.getItem('hide') == 'none') { // если значение ключа hide "none"
  document.getElementById('idExid').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryb4uexf/3/

Comment: Обязательно сохранять в `localstorage` Если страница будет перезагружена , то надо будет еще проверять текущее значение в `localstorage`

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK так и надо

Answer (score 0):

Смотри как реализовано у меня, может натолкнёт на мысль. При нажатии на кнопку она вызывает функцию changeDiv, передавая параметр (свой айди) - что даёт тебе знать куда ты нажимаешь, ну и соответственно с этого ты можешь узнать на что ты НЕ нажал и поменять что тебе нужно.

По умолчанию в стиле элемента стоит display: none. (у того который изначально должен быть скрыт)

`<button id="idHere" onclick="changeDiv(this.id)">Button</button>`

```
function changeDiv(divID) {
    var ifclosed = document.getElementById(divID).style.display;

    if (ifclosed==='' || ifclosed==='none') {
        document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "block"; // show body div tag
    } else {
        document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "none"; // hide body div tag
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        var idVhod = document.getElementById('idVhod');
        var idExid = document.getElementById('idExid');
        idExid.style.display = localStorage.getItem('idExid');
        idVhod.style.display = localStorage.getItem('idExid') == 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none';

        function onClickThis(){
            if(localStorage.getItem('idExid') == 'none'){
                localStorage.setItem('idExid','inline');
                idVhod.style.display = 'none';
                idExid.style.display = 'inline';
              }
             else{
                localStorage.setItem('idExid','none');
                idVhod.style.display = 'inline';
                idExid.style.display = 'none';
             }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: не работает https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPMOVM

Comment: onclick посмотрите что вызываете)))

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmQLWY